# First use of backwards time travel in fiction?

Tags: time-travel, history-of

The [First use of time travel in fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75839/first-use-of-time-travel-in-fiction) question resulted in forwards time-travel as the accepted answer. So now I'm wondering about backwards time travel.

This answer from that question, which I would've accepted were it not in that question, is [WhatRoughBeast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/26289/whatroughbeast)'s:

> Memoirs of the Twentieth Century by Samuel Madden was published in 1733, and uses the idea that the author is given documents from 200 years in the future. While no person is shown travelling back in time, the documents may count.

So, are there any backwards time travel uses from even earlier than 1733?

Comment: Do you want to count stories that turn out to be dreams?

Comment: This is a very interesting question: forward time travel is something we all have experienced, even jumps in time due to falling asleep for an odd several minutes which no doubt led to stories like Rip van Winkel. But the idea of visiting the past might be a conceptual leap and the twist of time paradoxes I am betting did not occur before the 20th century. Anyway, damn good question.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Hmm... maybe? Likely yes, if it's treated as an actual time travel event instead of "I'm reliving my day in my dream"?

Comment: Quoting the TVTropes page for [Stable Time Loop](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/StableTimeLoop/Literature): "This trope is actually Older Than Feudalism, since, while time travel is a relatively new concept, prophecy (which is basically information time travel) is not, and Self-Fulfilling Prophecy is the earliest form of stable time loop."

Comment: "A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court" by Twain, or "The Chronic Argonauts" by H.G. Wells?

Comment: Someone else should feel free to write this one up if they know more about it (or feel like researching it a little), but wikipedia's [time travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#History_of_the_time_travel_concept) page mentions in the "History of the time travel concept" section that "The Chinese novel Supplement to the Journey to the West (c. 1640) by Dong Yue features magical mirrors and jade gateways that connect various points in time" including travel to the "World of the Ancients" along with the "World of the Future", though the whole story turns out to be a dream.

Comment: @Malady: I think the best example would be a story in which an action in the past traveled to affected the time from which the character traveled and I do not believe that was really even explored in The Time Machine novel -- again, I suspect first was found in 20th century.

Comment: @releseabe - The [History of the time travel concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel#History_of_the_time_travel_concept) section of the "time travel" wiki article I mentioned above features a supernatural story of interfering with the past and causing a changed present, Edward Everett Hale's "Hands Off" from 1881, where an unnamed being "interferes with ancient Egyptian history by preventing Joseph's enslavement", resulting in an alternate history.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Interesting that the man who anticipate artificial satellites might be the first to have this idea. Except, isn't it natural for your species to wish that something else had happened, that you had made a different decision? It is a story in which the past still exists as a place to travel to (which may be in the story u cite) that is interesting to me.

Comment: "A Christmas Carol" from 1843 predates "A Connecticut Yankee..."  and "Hands Off"

Comment: As noted in that "History of the time travel concept" wiki, there is also ["An Anachronism; or, Missing One's Coach"](https://books.google.com/books?id=jfPAwAnj9JUC&pg=RA4-PA701#v=onepage&q&f=false) from 1838, where a 19th century character finds himself in the past and interacts with [Bede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede), though on p. 703 the narrator notes the possibility it was a dream, saying a "sceptical reader" may believe he "nodded and slept" when he sat by a tree before the experience, but he says "This explanation of what follows I am, however, resolved not to admit".